# Are variables in the main methods static

Tags: c#, .net, static

Its a well known fact that a static method can work only on static members.

```
public static void Main()
{
    Test t1 = new Test();
}
```

Here the `Main` method is static, but I haven't declared `t1` as static. Is it implicitly static?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, it's a *local* variable. Local variables behave the same way whether they're declared in static methods or instance methods.

As a *very rough* guide (captured variables etc introduce complications):

- Instance variables: one variable per instance
- Static variables: one variable for the type itself
- Local variables (including parameters): one separate variable for each method call

Comment: this answer has already been accepted. You just haven't clicked it yet :-D

Answer (score 10):

> Its a well known fact that a static method can work only on static members

This is not a fact; this is a falsehood. There is no restriction whatsoever; static methods have full access to all members of their type:

```
class C 
{
    private int x;
    static C Factory()
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.x = 123;
    }
}
```

Factory is a static method; it has access to the private instance members of any instance of C.

Comment: @Eric: As mentioned by Jon, this is a local variable and it will have scope only in the C method. So I still believe that 'static method can work only on static members'. What do you say.

Comment: @vaibhav: I give a legal example of a static method doing work on non-static members. Therefore it cannot be true that a static method can work only on static members.

Comment: @vaibhav: Perhaps it would be helpful to make Eric's point totally explicit: `x` is an instance member of type `C`, and yet this instance member is legally used within static method `Factory`.  The fact that `c` is a local is irrelevant to this point (it could just as easily have been passed in to the method as an argument, for example); what is important is that it is perfectly valid to use the member `x` even though it is not a static member.  You can not use an instance member without providing an instance, of course, if that is what you really mean by your objection.